# Bind to on scroll event of a DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to bind to the on scroll event of a DataTable which is set to scroll vertically.

Its obvious that a simple event binding does not work.

```
$('table tbody').on('scroll', function() {
    alert('');
});
```

I have created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ5RL/) here.

Does any one know an API method or work around that can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the table that's overflowing it's the parent div

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').on('scroll', function() {
    alert('');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ5RL/1/

Furthermore, I have never used this plugin So I don't know it's behavior. If the code above happens to not work, try the one below just in case.

```
$('table tbody').parent().on('scroll', function() {
    alert('');
});
```

BTW,  This is tested to work too.

Comment: This is great workaround. Its a pain that the API of DataTables is really not helpful.

Comment: no problem, if you run into anymore problem don't hesitate to ask

Comment: looking into it there is no scroll event for this plugin so my solution is correct ;) http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11383/expose-scroll-event/p1

Comment: Yeah I have tried searching whole site myself, I really thought I missed it. Its a great product, why no body thought of this event binding is out of my logical range.

Comment: Hey, the demo don't work today. Can you make an update? I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: This should be put in the `initComplete` handler of dataTables. It isn't always necessary, but is if data is loaded remotely, including the language settings.