# Scrolling in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hello how can i catch a scrolling event in jQuery datatable ?

I don't have a "bServerSide"

I have already tried :

```
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").scroll(function(){
    console.log("scroll");
});

$("#idOfMyTable").scroll(function(){
    console.log("scroll");
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418743/bind-to-on-scroll-event-of-a-datatable

Comment: hello, the given solution doesn't work in my case

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Have you tried attaching the `.scroll()` event to the `.dataTables_scrollBody` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').on( 'scroll', function (e) {
```

is working, i just don't put it in my document ready...