# How can I scroll horizontally and vertically simultaneously?

Tags: datatables

I'm using Datatables for rendering my table, but I'd like to scroll vertically when the user scrolls horizontally. In other terms, I'd like the scrolling to be synchronized?

I've looked into the API but wasn't able to figure this one out.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You want the table to move diagonally? My eyes hurt just imagining that.

Comment: While it's really bad UX, that's exactly what I need due to the way my data is structured.

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding an event listener for when the table scrolls in the X direction to also scroll it in the Y direction.

Have a look at this link: [Bind to on scroll event of a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418743/bind-to-on-scroll-event-of-a-datatable).

The API doesn't actually control scrolling, it just sets up the table so it overflows the parent div.

An example of the kind of code you might write:

```js
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').on('scroll', function() {
     var scrollLeftVal = $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft();
     $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop(scrollLeftVal);
});
```

You would likely need to fine tune some things about it but the general idea might get you going in the right direction.